# How to add AI recommendation feature in to android app?

Tags: android

can I know how can I add AI recommendation feature to my Android Java App? My objectives is let the app to have the ability to recommend other related product based on user's preference.

Answer (score 0):

For android app ML, I would recommend checking out [Google ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides)

I don't know much about android development, but their ML Kit seems like a good start.

EDIT: I found this as well, hopefully will help you can toggle from Kotlin and Java. [Generate smart replies with ML Kit on Android](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/smart-reply/android#java)

Answer (score 0):

This task is usually performed on the backend side where all data and user search history is available.

Later this is exposed through  some sort of HTTP / GraphQL / GRPC endpoint which the Android app queries using internet.

Finally the android app loops through the data received from the backend and  displays a list of nice items